# Use XML file selected in Form1 in Form2

Tags: xml, vb.net

First: I'm new to VB but trying to learn as much as I can through this project.

I want to use a XML file (location selected in Form1) in Form2.

I can not seem to make the doc.Load() in Form2 call the in Form1 selected XML file. I tried to call doc.Load(Form1(fullpath)) but that does not work.

I use the following code (VB2015) in Form1 to select the XML file location:

```vb
Private Sub BtnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSearch.Click
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Try
        Dim MyFolderPath As String = "[folderpath]"
        Dim MyFileType As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles(MyFolderPath, "[filetype]")

        If MyFileType.Length > 0 Then
            For Each fullpath As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(MyFolderPath, [filetype])

                FullPathsToPrograms.Add(fullpath)

                CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileName(fullpath))
            Next
        Else
    End Try
End Sub
```

In Form2 I try to call the in Form1 selected XML file with the following code:

```vb
Private Sub BtnScan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnScan.Click
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()

    doc.Load(Form1(fullpath))

    For Each node As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("/[node1]/[node2]")

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, vbscript is not VB.NET (the tags tell you so) and you forgot to read [Ask] and/or take the [Tour]

Comment: What is your problem ? Where do you stuck ?

Comment: Thanks Ansgar Wiechers for improving the formatting. Thanks Plutonix and Mukul for pointing out the flaws in my post. I've edited the post. I hope someone can help me with this one.

Comment: First, please use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx). I suspect that it will point out some problems for you that if you fix them will get you some way towards making a working program.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, it did point out some problems but I still am not able to call the XML file from Form1

Comment: I reworked the adding of items in the CheckedListBox1 containing the fullpath. adressing this object in Form2 works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I on top of Form2 had to add:

```
Shared Property filePath As String = my.Forms.Form1.CheckedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
```

Now I can use

```
    doc.Load(filepath)
```